# Pine Script count number of bars since histogram peak

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to sum up the value of the histogram after it reaches a peak.
I have tried the following code, but it gives me the following error:

*invalid 'Length' argument(0.0) in the "sum" function. it must be >0*

```
LocalHistLow = ta.lowest(hist,40)
b = ta.barssince(LocalHistLow)
var bool Condition = false
if math.abs(math.sum(hist,b)) > math.sum(hist,b)
Condition := true
else 
Condition := false
```

I don't understand why the value of b is smaller than 0 and how to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

My full code is the followed and it gives me the study error method mentioned above

```
//@version=5
indicator("MACD_Exaustion_strategy", overlay = true)
// getting input
bars = input(title = "Length of Lookback", defval=40)
histlookback = input(title = "MACD Loockback", defval=50)
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

///////////////////////////////////// finding the local lowest close and the highest close
LocalHigh = ta.highest(close,bars) 
LocalLow = ta.lowest(close,bars)

/////////////////////////////////////////////calculating the MACD
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
///////////////////////////////////finding Price Extreams
/// Highs
var bool PriceHigh = false
if close[1] == LocalHigh
    PriceHigh := true 
else if close[2] == LocalHigh and hist[1] > hist[2]
    PriceHigh := true 
else if close[3] == LocalHigh and hist[1] > hist[2]
    PriceHigh := true
else 
    PriceHigh := false
/// Lows
var bool PriceLow = false
if close[1] == LocalLow 
    PriceLow := true 
else if close[2] == LocalLow and hist[1] < hist[2]
    PriceLow := true 
else if close[3] == LocalLow and hist[1] < hist[2]
    PriceLow := true
else 
    PriceLow := false
    
//Finding Histogram Extreams
LocalHistHigh = ta.highest(hist,histlookback) 
LocalHistLow = ta.lowest(hist,histlookback) 

//Break Back Condition/////////////////////

//breaking bear back (for longing)
b = (ta.barssince(LocalHistLow) + 1 )

var bool condition1 = false
if math.abs(math.sum(hist,b)) > math.sum(hist,b)
    condition1 := true
else 
    condition1 := false
    
//breaking bull back (for shorting) 
c = ( ta.barssince(LocalHistHigh) + 1) 
var bool condition2 = false
if math.abs(math.sum(hist,c)) > math.sum(hist,c)
    condition2:= true
else
    condition2 := false
    
Buy = (PriceLow == true and close>= open and condition1 == true)
plotshape(Buy, style = shape.circle, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, size = size.tiny )
```

thanks again!

Comment: Didn't have any issues with a simple test code. Need to see your whole code.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I posted the full code in the original post that is generating the error. I tried to work around the issue with the 0 value by adding a +1 to guarantee that the length would at least be 1 but that seem to have not worked either.

Answer (score 0):

thank you @Daveatt for pointing me in the right direction.

I thought that `ta.barssince()` returns 0 at the initial value, however after some more reading I found that instead of 0, when the condition is first met, it returns `n/a` values, that's why changing the code to `b = (ta.barssince(LocalHistLow) + 1 )` didnt work.

However Pine Script has a built in function `nz()` that replaces an `n/a` value with 0. so `b = nz(ta.barssince(LocalHistLow)) + 1`  solves my problem, now the value will always be 0.

This solution is a little bit inaccurate as it will count 1 more bar than intended. however my main goal for this chain of codes is to find out if the histogram has crossed over the 0 line or not since its local MAX / Min. And this is my quick and dirty solution to getting there.

I am new to all this and welcome any feed back and critique!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe test this
`LocalHistLow = ta.lowest(hist,40) != ta.lowest(hist,40)[1]`

Also, when your condition when true, barssince will be at 0 for that candle where it becomes true
Maybe that's where your error message is trying to say

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! the suggestion sadly didnt work, I tried to work around the initial bar being 0 by adding +1 to the length set up. I assumed that way the length would always at least be 1, but im getting the same study error. 
I posted my full code in the original post :)